# Cloning a database in AWS data catalog

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I have a database in the AWS data catalog with name abc-prod-db. This has around 25 tables with data. I want to copy this over into a new database called abc-prod-db-bkup. What is the easiest way to accomplish this?

Comment: Great question, let me know if you find out the answer :)